# NodeJs/Mongoose - increment an integer value in mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to increment an integer value in mongo db using NodeJs/Mongoose code. However, it does nothing.

Here is the Mongo Document in which I am trying to increment the value ratings.likes by 1

```
{
    "_id" : "some-recipe",
    "name" : "Some Recipe",
    "ratings" : {
        "votes" : 234,
        "stars" : 4.5,
        "likes" : 3
    }
}
```

Here is the code to update the like count

```
router.put('/:id/like', function(req, res){
   var id = req.params.id;
   console.log('Register like with id:' + id);

   models.Recipe.update(id, {$inc: {"ratings.likes":1}}, function (err, responsePayload) {
     if(err){
       console.log(err)
       res.json({error:err});
     }
     if (responsePayload == null){
        console.log("Encountered error : " + err);
        res.status(404).json({error: 'Resource (' + id + ') Not found'})
     } else {
      console.log("Got this, after like :" + JSON.stringify(responsePayload));
      res.json(responsePayload);
     }
   });

});
```

Here is the resonse from update statement

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0
}
```

Comment: Try to execute your command in Mongo console and check the result.

Comment: Try `models.Recipe.update({_id: id}...`

Comment: @AmiramKorach still get the same response even when I explicitly mention the id  ... also the command works fine from console

Comment: Try to find the document with this id before you update it. Do you get something?

Comment: Yes, if I add find before update it works fine. It returns the right document.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an error? You forgot to return `return res.json({error: err})`